# well posed and Lipschitz condition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I encountered some problems about well posed and Lipschitz condition in the numerical analysis lecture.

> **Theorem:** Suppose $D=\left\{\left(t,y\right)|0\leq t\leq 1,-\infty\le y\le \infty\right\}$ . If $f$ is continuous
>   and satisfies a Lipschitz condition in the variable $y$ on the set $D$, then the initial value
>   problem

Does $f$ satisfy a Lipschitz condition on $D=\left\{\left(t,y\right)|0\leq t\leq 1,-\infty\le y\le \infty\right\}$ .
Can the above theorem be used to show that the initial problem $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=f(t,y)$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, $y(0)=1$ is well posed.

- $f(t,y)=e^{t-y}$
- $f(t,y)=\frac{1+y}{1+t}$
- $f(t,y)=\cos(ty)$
- $f(t,y)=\frac{y^{2}}{1+t}$

I think four of them fulfill Lipschitz condition  as I can partial derivative exist and is continuous but the well posed part I am not sure, what should I do? thanks.

Comment: You also need that the first derivative is bounded to get this kind of global Lipschitz condition.

Comment: how about the wellposed ?how to define if it is well posed?

Comment: In this context "well-posed" should mean the existence of a solution at all, uniqueness you already covered. You want solution functions on $[0,1]$ without singularities or gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Brother what remains here is for you to show whether each of these functions is continuous on D or not. If a function is continuous in D, then it is well-posed given that it satisfies Lipschitz condition. For more details read a theorem in Burden and Faires, Numerical Analysis, Ninth Edition, Chapter 5 page 263. Good Luck.

According to that theorem, if $f(t,y)=\cos(ty)$ , then $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y), \ y_0=\alpha$ is well-posed, because $f(t,y)=\cos(ty)$ is not only continuous in D but it is also satisfying Lipschitz Condition

Comment: This argument is wrong, as the Lipschitz condition is only local, the first derivative is not bounded, as $e^{-y}\to\infty$ for $y\to-\infty$. A closer inspection or a transformation of the problem might save the well-posedness, but this effort goes above the half-cited theorem.

Comment: No it is not wrong, brother because the definition of D is not correct as requested by the one asking the question brother.

Comment: I have done corrections @LutzL, please vote upwards, my answer is now 100% correct.